# React / React-Router/ Express / Heroku routing issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, react-router

I've deployed a React/Express app on Heroku.  I'm using BrowserRouter.  Everything worked fine locally.  My issue is the backend routes are not working.  The only route that works is the catchall route.  The catchall route is also being called three times for some reason.  I console logged the request path using 'req.path' to see which path was being called.  It should have been '/google'.  Instead the three calls give three different logs for req.path.  They are: '/static/css/main.814455d3.chunk.css.map', '/static/js/main.06bdb7f0.chunk.js.map', '/static/js/1.1baafe13.chunk.js.map'.  I'm hoping someone can help.

I've been stuck for over a day now.  Here are my package.json and static.json from the client side:

static.json

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
  "/**": "index.html"
 }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "workout_tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
     "axios": "^0.18.0",
      "jw-paginate": "^1.0.2",
      "jw-react-pagination": "^1.0.7",
       "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
      "query-string": "^6.2.0",
      "random-id": "0.0.2",
      "react": "^16.5.2",
      "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
      "react-headroom": "^2.2.2",
       "react-icons-kit": "^1.1.6",
      "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
       "react-scripts": "^2.0.5",
      "react-swipe-to-delete-component": "^0.3.4",
      "react-swipeout": "^1.1.1",
      "redux": "^4.0.0",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    },
   "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },

      "devDependencies": {
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5"
        },
       "proxy":"localhost:4000",
     "browserslist": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]

   }
```

And this is my package.json from express

```
     {
  "name": "expresstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app to test express and mysql",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start":"node app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is part of the code from the server.  I omitted the other routes as none besides the catchall route are being called anyway.

```
let express = require("express");
let cors= require("cors");
let mysql = require("mysql");
const util = require("util");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportSetup = require("./config/passport-setup");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const flash= require("connect-flash");
const path= require("path");

console.log("process env");
console.log("-------");
console.log(process.env.PWD);

const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge:24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys:[keys.session.cookieKey]   
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log("inside prod");
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
} 

let connection =keys.connection;

app.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google",{

    scope:['profile'],
    failureFlash:"failure"

}),(req,res)=>{
    // console.log(req.flash());
    console.log("/google route");
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
let http = require("http");
let server = http.createServer(app,(req,res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origiin": "*"})
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    console.log("catchall");
    console.log(req.hostname);
    console.log(req.path);
    console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client', 'build', 'index.html'));
})

server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on "+ port)
});
```

Here is my folder structure:

[Link to pic of my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnDB1.png)

EDIT: I got it working, here is the code that works.  I don't know why it works, though.  I just tried some things I found on blogs for React/Express/Heroku projects. If anyone can tell me why it works it would be greatly appreciated.

```
let express = require("express");
let cors= require("cors");
let mysql = require("mysql");
const util = require("util");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportSetup = require("./config/passport-setup");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const flash= require("connect-flash");
const path= require("path");

console.log("process env");
console.log("-------");
console.log(process.env.PWD);

const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");



let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge:24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys:[keys.session.cookieKey]   
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log("inside prod");
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
} 




let connection =keys.connection;


app.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google",{

    scope:['profile'],
    failureFlash:"failure"

}),(req,res)=>{
    // console.log(req.flash());
    console.log("/google route");
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
let http = require("http");
let server = http.createServer(app,(req,res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origiin": "*"})
});

app.get("/service-worker.js", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client","build", "service-worker.js"));
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    console.log("catchall");
    console.log(req.hostname);
    console.log(req.path);
    console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client', 'build', 'index.html'));
})

server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on "+ port)
});
```

Comment: A part of your main js and server js would help us see if there is something else going on, for example to see how you are routing in the front end and back end.

Comment: I've added the server file

Comment: you said `I omitted the other routes as none besides the catchall route are being called anyway` but you also say in the question `My issue is the backend routes are not working`. I'm lost, what is your issue then? which routes are not working?

Comment: I got it working and I posted the working code.  I'm not sure why it works, though.  I added app.use(express.static(__dirname)) near the top and I added a route for "/service-worker.js".  I notice that my service-worker.js file imports a  "precache-manifest" file that contains the paths that I said were being called in the original post.  If you have any insight as to why it works now and why it wasn't working before I would be very grateful if you'd share.